# Access SSDT without a database project

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

Is it possible to access the SQL Server Data Tools menu and features **without** having a database project? I want to compare two databases without creating or opening a database project.

Comment: Have you tried using a third party tool like SQL Compare?  If VS isn't working, might be a good option.

Comment: You should be able to do so. I opened up my VS shell and used the "SQL" menu to access the compare options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL Server menu has been moved under them main Tools menu in recent Visual Studio updates. You can use this to start a Schema Compare or Data Compare without opening a project:

[image: Schema Compare via the Tools menu]

Alternatively go to View -> SQL Server Object Explorer, connect to your server from there, and right-clicking on any database will give you the same options:

[image: Schema Compare via SQL Server Object Explorer]